# Creating a row that spans the width of the screen using bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a layout similar to [this one](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/) where the different sections span the entire width of the screen. I was looking at the html/css for the layout and couldn't figure out why my view was not doing the same. (I am relatively new to creating pages).

I am using php to make creating the pages easier so I have a few files.

```css
.jumbotron{
    background: gray; 

    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px; 
}

.jumbotron p, h1 {
    text-align: center;

}


.nav {
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;  
    background-color: red;
    height: 10%;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;  
}



.container #about {
    background: blue; 
    height: 50%; 
}

.container #me {
    background: blue; 
    height: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="dist3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> 
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</li>
            </ul><!--END .nav-->
        </div><!--END .wrapper-->
    </div><!--END .header-->

    <div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Example</h1>      
        <p>Example paragraph </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="about">
                <span class="name">ABOUT</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="more">
                <span class="name">MORE</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div> <!--END MAIN CONTAINER-->
</body>
</html>
```

The rows don't extend to the edge of the screen. The views are also not aligned. I know it is a lot to look at, but I could not find any resource online with an example, or a simple template for me to take a look at.

Comment: You are probably looking for `container-fluid`, which can be used in place of `container` and always stretches to take up the entire width of the viewport.

Comment: That extends it more, but it does not extend all of the way.

Comment: You are nesting the .container. Download that template and play around. You are not to put a .container inside a .container anywhere. Jumbotron is full width but if you wrap it with another element (.container) then it will fix the width. Look at the .container class in the unpacked CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap you can put the 12 column grid in a `.container` or a `.container-fluid`. The first is used if you want to grid to span a maximum of 1170 pixels, the latter if you want it to span the entire screen. Both have a horizontal padding of 15 pixels on each side to keep its content have some distance from the edge of the screen. For text this is a good thing to have, however as you note it's nice if a background color or image does span the entire width.

If you take a look at the theme you linked (see http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/) you might notice that the  `.container` and `.container-fluid` classes they use also don't span the entire width of the screen. They surround them with other elements, e.g. `<section class="success" id="about">`, on which they put a background color.

See this example where i've put a `<section>` with a `.pink` or `.green` background color around the containers:

```css
.pink {
  background-color: #f99;
}

.green {
  background-color: #9f9;
}

section {
  padding-bottom: 20px;  
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="pink">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>.container-fluid</h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">Column one</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">Column one</div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="green">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>.container</h3></div>
    </div>    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">Column one</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">Column one</div>      
    </div>
  </div>  
</section>
```

P.S. in your example the `<a>` tags aren't closed with a `</a>` tag, plus the `.container` after the `.jumbotron` isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with extending rows is simple, add the following rule:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It solves the problem that I understood for your question. If that's not what you're after perhaps try rephrasing your problem.